# How can I change the font for all the numbers in Classic Thesis?

Tags: fonts, classicthesis

I am using Classic Thesis v. 4.5 (https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/downloads/) and I do not like the numbers for the section headers, tables, references, etc...   Why?
There is no consistency.
Look..

**Reference number vs number in \texttt{}**
[image]

**Section number vs section number at top part of the page**
[image]

**Numbers in SI package command vs normal numbers.**
[image]

How can I change the font for the numbers? I tried all the options at the bottom of the file `classicthesis-config.tex` without success.

Thanks.

Comment: Which engine do you use to compile?

Comment: @murpholinox This is not just classicthesis, this is classicthesis plus arsclassica, right? All fonts should use, or not, so called Old Style Figures (osf)

Comment: @samcarter I use Texstudio, which uses pdflatex by default. Should I change to something else? (Not sure if it will work with something else. I can try.)

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Yes. It is classicthesis plus arsclassica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is not classicthesis alone, you're using arsclassica as well. Iwona font, for some reason, only shows oldstyle figures when the numbers are smallcaps - and this only happens with pdflatex, not xelatex or lualatex. Thus you'll need to change the line

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
```

in your Contents.tex to

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textsc{\thesection}\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
```

---

---

To stop using Oldstyle figures, though, you'll need to set the classicthesis option `palatino=false`, and call the package mathpazo witout the osf option:

```
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
```

Check that \sectionmark is now defined as

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
```

wherever you see it (arsclassica.sty, Contents.tex) 
AND
replace all the `\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}` with `\thesection` in `\titleformat` commands of arsclassica.sty.

Comment: This is confusing... i think your last `\renewcommand{}` is wrong. Should be the second one. Right?

Comment: @murpholinox No, it's correct. It regulates how Iwona sans serif is typeset: you want to avoid Iwona small caps because they will show oldstyle figures (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures) again.

Comment: So.. in `Contents.tex` I should have the second line and in `arsclassica.ct` (which I guess is a modified .sty file that comes within the zip file) I should have the third line? Because I am doing that and it works for the references and the `\texttt{}` numbers, but not for the section numbers.

Comment: I've updated my answer. No numbers should be typeset as  Iwona sans serif small caps, because these show as oldstyle figures. (As for the arsclassica.ct, you're using an experimental feature of classicthesis, I'm not sure if it's going to stay there or not)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you compile with pdflatex, you can switch of the old style numbers with

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pplx}

\begin{document}

test 1945 test

\end{document}
```

[image]