# Classicthesis v4.2 disable lowercase numbering (old style figures)

Tags: numbering, classicthesis

I am using classicthesis v4.2 through Overleaf with pdflatex. Additionally I am using MinionPro font which the aforementioned classicthesis package (sort of) supports.

My problem is similar to the one posted in the following thread: [How can I change the font for all the numbers in Classic Thesis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419384/how-can-i-change-the-font-for-all-the-numbers-in-classic-thesis)

That is, I would like to avoid having the numbering of sections, references, citations etc. being done in lowercase characters (see image). However; in my version of classicthesis I do not have the option to state "palatino=false".

I have also tried to force this change through: \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pplx} or usepackage{tgpagella}, but these changes messes with the rest of the config..

Is there another workaround for achieving non-lowercase numbering?

(.. I am not keen on using a newer version of classicthesis as it would require me to script/incorporate the MinionPro integration myself, and as you can tell, I'm fairly novice in Latex).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Classic Thesis takes some typographical inspirations from Bringhurst and lower case numbers with Minion Pro are absolutely in that spirit, so I would leave it as it is. But if you insist on modifying the typography, and you want someone to help you with an outdated package, please, at least, provide some compilable code.

Comment: Now, 4.2 is an ancient version, but if you have to use it, this should solve the problem: before you call classicthesis, use `\PassOptionsToPackage{textlf}{MinionPro}`. That's for text lined figures, instead of old style figures.

Comment: In newer versions like 4.6, you'd just set the palatino option to classicthesis to false, 
`palatino=false`, and have
`\usepackage[opticals, mathlf, textlf]{MinionPro}` before the call to classicthesis. 
Try this first.

Comment: Those not using the MinionPro font would have the palatino option to classicthesis set to false, 
`palatino=false` and in the document preamble call to package mathpazo without the osf option, like
`\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}` plus `\linespread{1.05}`

Comment: According to MinionPro package documentation you could also use `\figureversion{lining}` once classicthesis loads the package.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip - Why don't you turn your comments into an answer?

Comment: @DG' I need Tim C"s confirmation because I haven't tested this myself (I don't have MinionPro fonts)